# Reactor: change Scheduler from elastic to worker

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have the pipeline like this (contextMono is **Mono**):

```
    contextMono
      .map(this::doLogic)
      .map(this::doLogic1)
      .flatMap(ctx -> Mono
                   .fromCallable(() -> doWithData(ctx))
                   .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
      .map(this::buildReturnValue)
```

This pipeline executes in thread called like http-server-epoll-65 (epoll worker group). From flatMap executes in elastic's thread (because of **publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())**). This group (elastic) of threads uses for flatMap and for last map (**buildReturnValue**).

But I want **buildReturnValue** to be executed in group of epoll-workers threads (server-epoll-65 or other). 
I do not want to use **Schedulers.elastic()** for non-I/O (blocking) tasks.

How I can change back to workers-epoll group of Schedulers?

Comment: You could use publishOn after the flatMap but don't know how to retrieve the previous scheduler used before the flatMap.

Comment: @JEY yes, I know this trick, I can use publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()) but it is not good enough, because it will use extra threads.